# How can I sort data with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a little React application about Pokemons. I have in DB informations about all of them (about 900+).

They all contain an id field, which is an integer from 1 to 900+.

But the problem is when I do a request like this :

```
firebase.database().ref(`mydb`).orderByChild('id').startAt(1).limitToFirst(limit).once('value')
```

The results are not correct: I have an id array like this: `[9,1, 10, 6, 4]`

Am I doing something wrong ?

Edit:
I add the result I got when I perform the request I wrote above, I added a custom_id field containing ids as strings, but I stille have an unordered result:

```
[
  {
    "base_experience": 239,
    "custom_id": "009",
    "height": 16,
    "id": 9,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/encounters",
    "name": "blastoise",
    "order": 12,
    "weight": 855
  },
  {
    "base_experience": 64,
    "custom_id": "001",
    "height": 7,
    "id": 1,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/encounters",
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "order": 1,
    "weight": 69
  },
  {
    "base_experience": 39,
    "custom_id": "010",
    "height": 3,
    "id": 10,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10/encounters",
    "name": "caterpie",
    "order": 14,
    "weight": 29
  },
  {
    "base_experience": 240,
    "custom_id": "006",
    "height": 17,
    "id": 6,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/encounters",
    "name": "charizard",
    "order": 7,
    "weight": 905
  },
  {
    "base_experience": 62,
    "custom_id": "004",
    "height": 6,
    "id": 4,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/encounters",
    "name": "charmander",
    "order": 5,
    "weight": 85
  },
  {
    "base_experience": 142,
    "custom_id": "005",
    "height": 11,
    "id": 5,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/encounters",
    "name": "charmeleon",
    "order": 6,
    "weight": 190
  },
  {
    "base_experience": 142,
    "custom_id": "002",
    "height": 10,
    "id": 2,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/encounters",
    "name": "ivysaur",
    "order": 2,
    "weight": 130
  },
  {
    "base_experience": 63,
    "custom_id": "007",
    "height": 5,
    "id": 7,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/encounters",
    "name": "squirtle",
    "order": 10,
    "weight": 90
  },
  {
    "base_experience": 236,
    "custom_id": "003",
    "height": 20,
    "id": 3,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/encounters",
    "name": "venusaur",
    "order": 3,
    "weight": 1000
  },
  {
    "base_experience": 142,
    "custom_id": "008",
    "height": 10,
    "id": 8,
    "is_default": true,
    "location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/encounters",
    "name": "wartortle",
    "order": 11,
    "weight": 225
  }
]
```

Comment: Rather than sorting on id why don't you try to insert "CreatedTime" and use sort on that? You can do it by Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP. It might help in future to get created time.

Answer (score 0):

You've not attached your database image, but with the order one thing is sure that these keys in your database are strings.
And when you order string data, it is ordered lexicographically.

So for numbers, this is the normal order:

1
9
10

But for strings, this is the normal order:

"9"
"1"
"10"

I don't think there is any operator in Firebase (nor in most other databases) to change this behaviour.

Instead, you will have to modify the data to get the behavior you want. So: store values that are in the order you need them when sorted lexicographically.

For numbers you can accomplish that by padding them with zeroes:

"001"
"009"
"010"

**EDIT:**
Now after Json, these values are stored in `id` field so the above thing does not apply to this.

You may however use a code like this, to do what you're trying:

```java
mDatabase
  .child("main_child")
  .orderByChild("id")
  .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(child.getKey());
      }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I am not sure this is my problem because chrome displays them as Int, not as string, but I was not sure, so I added a `custom_id` field with the 0 padding, but it's the same, I edit my original post with the JSON result, if it can help

Comment: @Azilhan can you try this update answer's code and tell if that works or not?

Comment: Well finally I changed my approach, instead of storing the entities within a object being a random Id, each parent is named according to their ID, and it works like that, so thank you !

Comment: @Azilhan, Glad that it works, Cheers!, if you found something useful from the answer consider marking it as correct and upvoting it. I'd appreciate that.